# Change variable value inside an array in a new array

Tags: php, arrays, variables

How to, and is it possible to add different value to a variable inside an array, but to simplify it possibly to do it with another array; i need to store processes and their cpu load on my page, but since process names are "ugly", i need to change their name to something normal looking

so far i have managed to extract top 5 of them (mostly the same every time) like this:

```
    $array[0] = "process1";
    $array[1] = "process2";
    $array[2] = "process3";
```

Now i want to add as many possibilities as possible to change some prettier values to them

```
$new_values = array(
"process1" == "Process name as i want it",
"process2" == "Second process"
);
```

So when i call say

```
$array[1]
```

i don't get "process2" but changed name ("Second process")

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this, using the **value** from the first array as the **key** for the `$new_values` array:

```
echo $new_values[$array[1]]; // Second process
```

**Edit:** I'll wrap this inside a function to check for the `$new_values` existence, otherwise fall back to the original value:

```
function displayPretty($key) {
    global $new_values; // get the $new_values array from global scope
    if(array_key_exists($key, $new_values))
        return $new_values[$key]; // return pretty name if it exists

    return $key; // return original value otherwise
}

echo displayPretty($array[1]);
```

This way, if you pass in `$array[1]` it will return the value from `$new_values` if it exists (e.g. `Second process` in this case), and if it doesn't (e.g. if you passed in `$array[5]` and that doesn't have a pretty definition in `$new_values`) it will just return what you passed in.

Comment: Side note: your syntax in the second array is incorrect, should be `=>`

Comment: Yep, figured that out, but now how can i call any $array[x] to display it's value, but if a value is inside new array to display the corrected value?